# Redux add state field, without re-initialising everything

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a webapp and already people using my application. I use redux-thunk to save the state in localStorage.

When I want to add a new field to my redux initial state, this is not automatically added to their store (because I use Redux-Thunk to save the state, and the new field does not exist on the saved state).

I only see the solution to reinitialise the redux state to add the new field. I could do this, but that would mean people are logged out to their application, which is not user friendly.

So my question: How can I add a field to the initalState, and add it automatically to the saved redux-thunk state?

I am using `react-redux`, `redux-toolkit` and `redux-thunk`

My code:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  user: authReducer,
  groups: groupReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: [thunk],
});
```

Comment: try custom action creators , they allow you to create your own action creators.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I found the solution after searching for one day. The name of the redux-toolkit tool `createMigrate` should be used. This is just a hard term to find via online search I guess.

Here is a tutorial I used to fix by problem:
https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/redux-persist-how-it-works-and-how-to-change-the-structure-of-your-persisted-store

The specifically say you should use `createMigrate` when

> 1. You need to keep the history of your modification.
> 2. You often change the form of your store and you have users in production local storage of
> 3. Your users are important to be kept.

In my case point 3 was applicable